# Get rid of decimals in Percent Formatter and savefig() OSError: [Errno22] Invalid Arguments

Tags: python, matplotlib

I made this plot

[image]

And I need to get rid of the decimals in the percents along the y axis.

Furthermore, I am getting an error when saving the figure. Code and Error message below.

```
plt.figure()
cm = plt.cm.rainbow
weight = np.ones(len(ozone)) / len(ozone)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(ozone, 50, weights = weight, color='green', ec = 'black', linewidth = .5)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1, decimals = None))

for i, p in enumerate(patches):
    plt.setp(p, 'facecolor', cm(i/25)) # notice the i/25



plt.ylabel('Relative frequency (%)')
plt.xlabel('Ozone mixing ratio (ppbv)')
plt.xlim(0,140)
plt.title('Urban JJA relative ozone frequency')
plt.tight_layout()    
plt.savefig('Urban Ozone Distribution.jpg')

>>> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Urban Ozone Distribution.jpg'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please decide about which one of these issues you want to ask a question.

Comment: your `savefig` works just fine for me. maybe try to remove the spaces.

Comment: Is that the actual filename you're using, or did you replace it for the purposes of creating the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`None` as a value for the decimals `PercentFormatter(1, decimals = None)` means "the number will be computed automatically" (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.PercentFormatter). Use `decimals=0`.